# How to extract text from all paragrahs on website that contain specific string

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having an issue via this [site](https://steemit.com/nigeria/@leopantro/50-yoruba-proverbs-and-idioms).
I want to extract my local language and it meaning in a tabular form

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res2 = requests.get('https://steemit.com/nigeria/@leopantro/50-yoruba-proverbs-and-idioms')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(res2.content,'html')

Yoruba = []
English = []
for ol in soup2.findAll('ol'):
   proverb = ol.find('li')
   Yoruba.append(proverb.text)
```

I successfully extracted my local language to a *list*, i also want to extract each sentence starting with the string `Meaning:` to another list eg: ['Your status in life dictates your attitude towards your peers','Behave in a mature manner so avoid bad reputation.'etc.]

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: after successfully extracting all my local language to a `list`, which is the code above, extracing it meaning to a `list` via the site above is the issue i have

Comment: You could provide a little snippet of equivalent HTML rather than referencing the website contents itself. See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply search for all paragraphs and check if the paragraphs text starts with "Meaning".

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res2 = requests.get('https://steemit.com/nigeria/@leopantro/50-yoruba-proverbs-and-idioms')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(res2.content,'html')

yoruba = []
english = []
for ol in soup2.findAll('ol'):
    proverb = ol.find('li')
    yoruba.append(proverb.text)

for paragraph in soup2.findAll('p'):
    if paragraph.text.startswith("Meaning:"):
        english.append(paragraph.text)

english = [x.replace("Meaning: ", "") for x in english]
print(english)
```

Prints out:

```
[' Necessity is mother of invention, creativity is often achieved after overcoming many difficulties.',
 ' Everyone looks the same on the outside but everyone has problems that are invisible to outsiders.',
...
```

Answer (score 3):

This script scrapes proverbs, translations and meanings and creates a pandas DataFrame from them. The *meanings* list is inside `data['Meaning']`:

```
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://steemit.com/nigeria/@leopantro/50-yoruba-proverbs-and-idioms')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')

data = {'Yoruba':[], 'Translation':[], 'Meaning':[]}
for youruba, translation, meaning in zip(soup.select('ol'), soup.select('ol + p'), soup.select('ol + p + p')):
    data['Yoruba'].append(youruba.get_text(strip=True))
    data['Translation'].append(re.sub(r'Translation:\s*', '', translation.get_text(strip=True)))
    data['Meaning'].append(re.sub(r'Meaning:\s*', '', meaning.get_text(strip=True)))

# print(data['Meaning']) # <-- your meanings list

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                               Yoruba                                        Translation                                            Meaning
0                         Ile oba t'o jo, ewa lo busi  When a king's palace burns down, the re-built ...  Necessity is mother of invention, creativity i...
1   Gbogbo alangba lo d'anu dele, a ko mo eyi t'in...  All lizards lie flat on their stomach and it i...  Everyone looks the same on the outside but eve...
2                           Ile la ti n ko eso re ode                             Charity begins at Home  A man cannot give what he does not have good o...
3                        A pę ko to jęun, ki ję ibaję  The person that eat late, will not eat spoiled...  It is more profitable to exercise patience whi...
4        Eewu bę loko Longę, Longę fun ara rę eewu ni  There is danger at Longę's farm (Longę is a na...  You should be extremely careful of situations ...
5   Bi Ēēgun nla ba ni ohùn o ri gontò, gontò na a...  If a big masquerade claims it doesn't see the ...  If an important man does not respect those les...
6   Kò sí ęni tí ó ma gùn ęşin tí kò ní ju ìpàkó. ...  No one rides a horse without moving his head, ...  Your status in life dictates your attitude tow...
7               Bí abá so òkò sójà ará ilé eni ní bá;  He who throws a stone in the market will hit h...  Be careful what you do unto others it may retu...
8             Agba ki wa loja, ki ori omo titun o wo.     Do not go crazy, do not let the new baby look.  Behave in a mature manner so avoid bad reputat...
9                      Adìẹ funfun kò mọ ara rẹ̀lágbà         The white chicken does not realize its age                                   Respect yourself
10                           Ọbẹ̀ kìí gbé inú àgbà mì   The soup does not move round in an elder’s belly                 You should be able to keep secrets

... and so on
```